# Empty page show when running jupyter notebook under a virutal env in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I used Anaconda on Windows with Python 3.7.

I can run 'jupyter notebook' under root (base) environment and all the notebook files show up on the web browser.

However, when I call 'jupyter notebook' on my virtual environment named 'tensorflow_env'. It shows an empty page on the web browser.

Note that I have installed both jupyter and nb_conda on my tensorflow_env virtual environment.

Any thought? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the static files are missing in the new environment `tensorflow_env`. Try to run `jupyter lab build` in that environment to rebuild all static files (mainly js files).

Comment: I have the same problem, but my jupyter is installed in environment created with pipenv and Python 3.7. After I activate the environment with '''pipenv shell''' I type '''jupyter notebook''' and a blank page appears on address http://localhost:8888/tree

Comment: @gdlmx thanks for your comments. I will follow your suggestion and will report back.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it turned out to be an [issue with notebook 5.7.6](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467), downgrading to 5.7.4 fixed the issue for me:

`conda install notebook=5.7.4`

to see changes remember to clear your cache (ctrl+shift+r)

Comment: I tried this, and it resolved the problem. Now there is another problem, It can't connect to kernel